# glDrawElements EXC_BAD_ACCESS using VBO's

Tags: exc-bad-access, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

i'm having this issue with VBO's that I don't really understand. My problem is solved by accidentally changing the last parameter in the glVertexAttribPointer method call. So, I'm looking for an answer as to **WHY** this is suddenly working or why my previous code isn't working anymore. (just to get a better understanding on opengl)

**Struct:**

```
typedef struct 
{
    float position[3];
    float color[4];
} Vertex;
```

**Without VBOs:**

```
// Get pointers to the data
GLsizei stride = sizeof(Vertex);
const GLvoid *pCoords = &squareVertices[0].position[0];
const GLvoid *pColors = &squareVertices[0].color[0];

// Setup pointers to positions and colors
glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pCoords);
glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pColors);

// Draw
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(squareVertices) / sizeof(Vertex));
```

**With VBOs (this gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS)**

```
// Stide
GLsizei stride = sizeof(Vertex);

// Setup pointers to positions and colors
glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

// Draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(squareIndices) / sizeof(squareIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

So, the only thing that actually differs is the `glVertexAttribPointer` call which had a pointer to the data and now has fixed numbers. Can anyone elaborate on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a VBO is active, the last parameter to `glVertexAttribPointer` is not really a pointer,  but the offset inside the vertex buffer object type-cast to a pointer. That's how VBOs work: the data has been copied to some memory managed by the graphics driver, you don't know its address. In fact, it might not even have a normal address when it's stored somewhere on your graphics card.

The rest is cheating around the C/C++ type system. The type system is nowhere near smart enough to understand that `glVertexAttribPointer`'s last argument should be a pointer-sized integer offset when a VBO is active, and a pointer otherwise. So to the C++ compiler, this has to look like a pointer all the time, because that is how `glVertexAttribPointer` (or rather, it's predecessors `glVertexPointer` and friends) where defined originally. When it is really just a number, we just use a type cast to cheat the compiler.

Comment: Wow! That was a fast anwser. Really appreciated. Cristal clear ;)